# iRobot Create 2 opcodes, data bytes and Realterm

Tags: irobot-create, serial

I recently purchased an iRobot Create 2.
To connect to it, I am using RealTerm
Although I can send opcode commands that do not require a Data Byte (128, 173, 133, etc), I cannot figure out the format for opcodes with data bytes

For example, I want to turn on the power LED to full brightness.
I have tried the following formats, but to no avail:

139,4,0,254

139 4 0 254

139004000254

13940254

Any direction is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my own question.
The iRobot needs to be in Safe or Full mode in order to control the LEDs.
So, I was entering the numbers correctly (139 4 0 254), but needed to send the command for Safe (131) or Full (132) first.